# Inverse Kinematic Panel disabled from Bone tab

Tags: armature, bones, inverse-kinematics

I cannot restrict the rotation of a Bone in Blender... I have done it on the previous project, but now it is disabled and I cannot figure out why..

[image]

Any ideas would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Stupid me...

As soon as I added an IK (inverse Kinimatics) Constrain from the Bone Constrains tab, it worked....

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As a more up to date answer, since the UI has been overhauled:
[image]

1. Make sure you are in pose mode.
2. Go to bone constraints and select Inverse Kinematics from the drop down menu.